# Adding new row in Scala-Spark dataframe based on a existing row

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in Json dataframe like below.

```
{"nm": 1233, "date": "2017-01-23", "name": [],"id": "9253194"}
{"nm": 1234, "date": "2017-01-23", "name": [],"id": "9253196"}
{"nm": 1235, "date": "2017-01-23", "name": [],"id": "9253195"}
```

how can add a new row with an indexed column to insert in to elastic search in scala.

```
{"create": {"_type": "usd", "_id": "92531964", "_index": "amount"}}
{"nm": 1233, "date": "2017-01-23", "name": [],"id": "9253194"}
{"create": {"_type": "usd", "_id": "92531966", "_index": "amount"}}
{"nm": 1234, "date": "2017-01-23", "name": [],"id": "9253196"}
{"create": {"_type": "usd", "_id": "92531965", "_index": "amount"}}
{"nm": 1235, "date": "2017-01-23", "name": [],"id": "9253195"}
```

here _id I am deriving from existing column and _type, _index are constants.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap`:

```
input.flatMap { x => Seq(x, transform(x)) }
```

Since these records have different schema, you might have to output them just as strings.